# Find Lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $\frac{n}{a^{n+1}}$ $\left(a+\frac{a^{2}}{2}+...+\frac{a^{n}}{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> **Question**
>   Find Lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{n}{a^{n+1}}$$\left(a+\frac{a^{2}}{2}+...+\frac{a^{n}}{n}\right)$ , $a$ >1

**My Approach** I tried using [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)
But $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{a_{n + 1}} - {a_n}}}{{{b_{n + 1}} - {b_n}}} = $$   do not exist .I don't know any other method.

**Edit**

**I Got The solution**

Let $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} $= $a$+$\frac{a^{2}}{2}$+.......+$\frac{a^{n}}{n}$and
$\left\{ y_{n}\right\} =\frac{a^{n+1}}{n}$

Then Lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}{y_{n+1}-y_{n}}$=
lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{a^{n+2}}{n+1}-\frac{a^{n+1}}{n}}$=$\frac{1}{1-a}$

Comment: The last term doesn't fit the pattern started by the first two terms. Is it supposed to be $\frac{a^n}{n}$?

Comment: @jon  It was a typo. I fixed it

Comment: Using Cesaro-Stolz we see that the limit is equal to the limit of $(a^n/n) /(a^{n+1}/n-a^n/(n-1))$ which is same as the limit of $\dfrac{n-1} {(n-1)a-n} $ ie $1/(a-1)$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks Sir ,i was making very silly mistakes in computation